# Holomorphic function and series converges in the unit disk $ (|z_{k}| < 1) $

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

$ f $ is holomorphic in the unit disc , bounded and not identically zero and

$z_{1},z_{2},\ldots,z_{n},\ldots $ are its zeros$ (|z_{k}| < 1) $ , $a$ is a real number

My question is :for which values of $a$ that $ \sum_{n}(exp(|z_{n}|^2-a^2))  $ does converges ?

Comment: no, it's not -1, i mean just a question, i edit it now, thanks

Comment: yes, i thanks , i forget a parenthesis

Comment: I notice that you have posted 14 questions and never accepted an answer.  http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer  Why is that?

Comment: just i commente answer , and i don't know how i accepte answer , do u mean to do upvote ?

Comment: i w'ill accepte all interest answers to my precedent questionss, then thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.  $|z_n|^2-a^2$ lies in $[-a^2,1-a^2]$, so the terms of the sum do not go to zero.